gauge run specs command stops if one spec failed. How i can run all specs even if one failed?
I am using Javacript framework gauge +taiko+.
When I run :
gauge run specs

This command stops if one spec fail.
How i can run all specs even if one failed ?
I want to run specs in sequential order and all specs should run even if one spec fail instead of  should not stop execution.
Right-now I have 3 specs but if the second one fails, execution is stopped.

The default behavior when using Gauge for testing is to stop the execution if a specification fails. When running tests, you can use the --continue-on-failure flag if you wish to run all specs regardless of whether some fail.
